# How can I keep a docker debian container open?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, debian, dockerfile

I want to use a debian Docker container to test something, and by this I mean execute some commands in the debian bash console. I tried downloading the image using `docker pull debian` and then running it using `docker run debian`, but I get no output. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the docker container stay open until I close it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to explicitly run bash:

```
docker run -it debian /bin/bash
```

The `-i` means "run interactively", and `-t` means "allocate a pseudo-tty".

A good place to read a bit more is the section [Running an interactive shell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/basics/#running-an-interactive-shell) in the Quickstart documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the additional link to the documentation. I followed the Get Started guide but hadn't stumbled upon that source of docs.